# What is the next step in top-down brain simulation after spiking neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, models

[This paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fninf.2020.00016/full) from Yamazaki et al. describes a 68 billion spiking neural network model of the cerebellum. The simulation was about 600 times slower than real time, and the cerebellum is perhaps one of the more boring parts of the brain in terms of intelligent behavior, but this still seems like a significant step in the direction of meaningful top-down brain simulations.

To be clear, by top-down simulation, I'm referring to simulations that allow massive abstractions away from the biology of the nervous system in order to investigate and/or produce intelligence more directly, e.g. modern neural networks. This is in contrast to bottom-up simulation, which start with models of individual neurons (e.g. LIF, Hodgkins-Huxley) and add increasingly more realistic biophysical properties to them; these bottom-up simulations are geared towards testing hypotheses about low-level neurophysiology, rather than trying to produce or investigate intelligence per se.

My question, as someone very unfamiliar with these subfields, is: what are the most promising next steps for top-down brain simulation? Is it worth it to try to take more sophisticated network architectures like RNNs or transformers and make them spiking? Is it feasible to combine top-down and bottom-up simulation approaches, for example by organizing LIF models into a convolutional architecture (this particular example is likely impossible as I don't think the LIF neurons would be compatible with backpropogation)? Or should we think that the solution may not involve deep neural networks at all?